# Running Total added to Next partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @Temp table 
(    
  Grp int,
  Bal float,
  [Value] float    
)     

declare @Amt  float =1000;

Insert into @Temp(Grp,[Value])    
Values(1,10),(1,5),(1,15)
,(2,20),(2,5),(2,15)
,(3,50),(3,50)

select Grp,@Amt as Amount,Value,Bal from @Temp
```

Required Output:

```
Grp Amount Value Bal
1   1000    10  1000
1   1000    5   1000
1   1000    15  1000
2   1000    20  1030  ---(10+5+15)
2   1000    5   1030
2   1000    15  1030
3   1000    50  1070 ---- (20+5+15)
3   1000    50  1070
```

Balance calculated based on running total of 'Value' of Group1 added to Group2 and running total of group 2 added to balance of Group3 and soon

I know how to calculate the running total but I can't as sums are added to next partition.

Please help to get required result efficiently. I am using SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, t.amount + coalesce(t2.value, 0)
from @temp t outer apply
     (select sum(t2.value) as value
      from @temp t2
      where t2.grp < t.grp
     ) t2;
```

It is possibly more efficient to use aggregation and a running sum:

```
select t.*,
       (1000 + tt.running_value)
from @temp t join
     (select t.grp, sum(value) as value,
             sum(sum(value)) over (order by grp) - sum(value) as running_value
      from @temp t
      group by grp
     ) tt
     on t.grp = tt.grp;
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't fully support `range` window frames, so I don't think there is a convenient way to do this only with window functions.  But the `group by` will probably have much better performance.

Comment: Thanks @ Gordon...Is it possible do with window function  because total records in millions